# ChildBrowser plugin does not allow download links to be opened

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have used PhoneGap 1.4.1 to build a Windows Phone 7 app.

I need to open a browser link from the app that will download a PDF file. I have used the ChildBrowser plugin to allow a new browser instance to be opened when the user clicks on a link in my app.

On click of the link, a new browser instance does open, but it shows up a blank page. If I change the URL to be opened to any other website which does not download anything, it works!
But for any download attempt, it gets stuck.

Has anybody faced any similar situation with PhoneGap and Windows Phone 7.

Cheers!

Comment: do you get any solution fo this ??? please share... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the latest phonegap and grab the code from https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/ChildBrowser

Then run this function in the javascript
ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage = function(loc,geolocationEnabled)

you will need to change the word Phonegap to cordova in javascript file

Comment: URL moved to: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/WindowsPhone/ChildBrowser